# Extract both text in urls from table in page - beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract both text and urls in a table from a website but I only seem to be able to get the text. I am guessing this has something to do with the 
`text.strip` in my code but I am not how I can clean up the html tags without removing the url links in there. Here's what I've put together so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

start_number = 0
max_number = 5

urls=[]

for number in range(start_number, max_number + start_number):
    url = 'http://www.ispo-org.or.id/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=79:pengumumanpublik&catid=10&Itemid=233&showall=&limitstart=' + str(number)+ '&lang=en'
    urls.append(url)

data = []

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
    table = soup.find("table")
    table_body = table.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) # Get rid of empty values
```

Comment: You extract only the text from each `td` element. What would you like to get in case of `<td><a href="some.pdf">PT. Ichtiar Gusti Pudi</a></td>`?

Comment: @Jatimir, I would like to get the link to the pdf as a separate element in the list. It is something like this - `"images/notifikasi/619.%20Pengumuman%20Publik%20PT%20IGP.compressed.pdf"`. I will then use this and a base url to download the pdfs

Comment: Can you be little clearer about your expected output @Funkeh-Monkeh?

Comment: @SIM, basically I want a dataframe with all the information in the table inc. the links to the pdf's so I can iterate and download them into a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extract the `href` from the `<a>` element. For the purpose of the answer, I simplified the code not to worry about subsequent pages.

```
from collections import namedtuple

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.ispo-org.or.id/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=79:pengumumanpublik&catid=10&Itemid=233&showall=&limitstart=0&lang=en'

data = []
Record = namedtuple('Record', 'id company agency date pdf_link')

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.select('table > tbody > tr')

for row in rows[1:]:  # omit header row
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    fields = [td.text.strip() for td in cols if td.text.strip()]

    if fields:  # if the row is not empty
        pdf_link = row.find('a')['href']
        record = Record(*fields, pdf_link)
        data.append(record)
```

```
>>> data[0].pdf_link
'images/notifikasi/619.%20Pengumuman%20Publik%20PT%20IGP.compressed.pdf'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @Jatimir. Unfortunately, when I start looping through the urls, I get this `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: It appears that sometimes there are some additional empty rows. I updated the code in my answer so it deals with these cases.